# structure type and variable name

Tags: c

hi all 
i just wanted to know whether we can declare variable name as structure name.

for example

```
typedef struct
{
  char c;
}t;
```

then in some function can i use

```
fun()
{
  t t;
}
```

is this valid? if so then how compiler differentiate between them?

Comment: You can always compile it... I think the compiler will be able to differentiate, since you can tell when a variable/object is being declared vs being read/written/etc to.

Comment: @muntoo, you can compile it, but that doesn't tell you whether it's valid, just whether it works in your compiler.

Comment: Of course, if a psychopath was the next guy who looked at your code...

Comment: Google for lvalue and rvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is valid. If you do that, then the structure type is hidden in the enclosing scope and `t` refers only to the declared variable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but why would you want to? If you want bugs and errors to thrive in your project, then go right ahead and name variables after types.

Comment: Bravo, just because something is valid, that doesn't make it a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> `fun()
>   {
>     t t;
>   }`
>
> is this valid ?

No it is not. Return type of `fun()` is missing  and implicit `int` return type is deprecated.

However `void fun(){ t t ;}` is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

yes because each thing lives in a different place in the compilers understanding.

```
t t;
```

The compiler is expecting a type when it encounters the first t and it has a type called t.

**Edit: To address comments.**

I'm not talking about scope.

But since I've not written a compiler (only interpreters) I don't know the term. The compiler is expecting a token at the first t to be a type, it also knows what type have been declared up to that point. Since it see a name that refers to a type it's happy. Whereas if a token that wasn't a type was found there then it would rightly signal an error.

Comment: -1 because your are giving the wrong reason. `typedef` and variable names are in the same scope.

Comment: The terminology is that they are different types of token.

Answer (score 0):

parser first gets the data type and maintains a different table and later part as the variable name. So it works absolutely.